# Shell not showing properlly in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh

I'm using `zsh` with the Powershell theme and I have a customized prompt that works properly in iTerm, but it's not displaying correctly in VSCode. I have already made the setting for the terminal to `inherit`.

iTerm prompt:
[image: iTerm prompt]

VSCode prompt:

[image: Text]

Amy I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

My iTerm was using a different font, I had to change the one in Visual Studio to match it.